# Centos 7 - ping 8.8.8.8 (connect: Network is unreachable)

Tags: networking, centos, centos-7

I think I have a routing problem. I have set up a CentOS VM, it is connected to my network and I can ping other machines.

I cannot however ping anything outside of my network.

```
[root@localhost ~]# ping 8.8.8.8
connect: Network is unreachable
```

I also set up port forwarding on my router to forward SSH on port 22 to this machine and I cannot access it outside of my network (using putty).

Here is the output of `ip route`:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route
10.0.0.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.0.10
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3  scope link  metric 1002
```

Here is the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=10.0.0.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s3"
UUID="17eeb7fe-f11c-4b8b-83be-a9dd2281dda2"
DEVICE="enp0s3"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

Comment: You appear to be missing a default route.  So your machine only knows how to get to 10.0.0.* addresses.  Assuming a default .1 for the gateway, you  can add GATEWAY=10.0.0.1 to the file.

Comment: can you post the contents of `/etc/sysconfig/network` and `/etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Based on the errors, you need to update the files to look like this:

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="static"
IPADDR=10.0.0.10
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
NM_CONTROLLED=no
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s3"
UUID="17eeb7fe-f11c-4b8b-83be-a9dd2281dda2"
DEVICE="enp0s3"
ONBOOT="yes"
```

`/etc/sysconfig/network`:

```
NETWORKING=yes
HOSTNAME=centos7
GATEWAY=10.0.0.1
```

`/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: While there's nothing wrong with that resolv.conf, it's not needed to fix the routing.

Comment: true, but it will help for resolving domain names if that functionality is needed

Comment: I'm actually using the DNS servers provided by my ISP, I was just testing with `8.8.8.8` as it's easier to remember.

Comment: I had actually thought that it was a problem with the gateway not being specified (it is indeed 10.0.0.1). I just wasn't sure enough to actually take myself seriously. It works now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 8):

Add this command:

```
route add default gw [your gateway IP address]
```

Comment: that resolved it for me.  i had switched gateways, made adjustments to ifcfg, set link down, then back up, no internet.  this got the internet back. thanks!

Comment: this should be the correct answer IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just change it to `dhcp`, look for a proper IP and then set it to `static` with that IP?

Comment: that's a downgraded experience when you are dealing with servers, and not future proof at all. you want to design a network and rely on clear network documentation.

Answer (score -1):

**Add a default gateway**

```
# route add default gw 10.0.0.10 enp0s3
```

Comment: That’s not a permanent solution. And neither is his own PC the gateway.